# xcode - Library linking issue when including cocoapods library

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have checked online on trying to solve the issue, but so far none have worked.

Few have suggested removing the file under `../Xcode/DerivedData/`, but didn't do anything. I tried playing with the `Library Search Paths` and `Other Linker Flags`

Linker Flags:

`//:configuration = Debug
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"CocoaAsyncSocket" -framework -l"GHODictionary" -l"MDWamp" -l"MPMessagePack" -l"SocketRocket" -framework -l"icucore" -framework "Security"`

`//:configuration = Release
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"CocoaAsyncSocket" -framework -l"GHODictionary" -l"MDWamp" -l"MPMessagePack" -l"SocketRocket" -framework -l"icucore" -framework "Security"`

`//:completeSettings = some
OTHER_LDFLAGS`

I am trying to include this into xcode [MDWamp](https://github.com/mogui/MDWamp). I did `pod init` and included `MDWamp` in the podfile.

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Example' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Example
  pod "MDWamp"
end
```

I have been cleaning and rebuilding in hopes it fixes itself.
Was hoping this would be a simple include, but hasn't been working.

Edit:

Error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-fvftguwrkfoqgvaswdscaatwogtt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-fvftguwrkfoqgvaswdscaatwogtt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GHODictionary'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-fvftguwrkfoqgvaswdscaatwogtt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MDWamp'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-fvftguwrkfoqgvaswdscaatwogtt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MPMessagePack'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Example-fvftguwrkfoqgvaswdscaatwogtt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocketRocket'
ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

result from `pod install`:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using CocoaAsyncSocket (7.5.1)
Using GHODictionary (1.1.0)
Using MDWamp (2.2.4)
Using MPMessagePack (1.3.13)
Using SocketRocket (0.5.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 5 total pods installed.
```

The warnings were resolved by making the corresponding directory, I am unsure what negative that would cause in the future. Only issue that remains is the linker error.

Comment: When trying to use this pod getting this error :!] The platform of the target `ObjectiveC-2` (iOS 10.2) is not compatible with `MPMessagePack (1.3.8)`, which does not support `ios`.

Comment: @HarishGupta That is odd. This library has been tested and is suppose to work strictly for `Objective-C`. This library is even suggested when wanting to use `WAMP`. Is there anyway to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

So I was really only able to get it working on accident which was using the GUI version of `Cocoapods` and install it from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I tried a lot of solutions but I found this working fine.

Project -> Build Settings -> (SEARCH -> Library_search_path)

Open it and remove quotes from all

like

> "$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)" TO
>       $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)

For all three.